# No New Row Entry Added to Access Backend

Tags: sql, vb.net

so I made this code which is supposed to update the Delivery table in my MS Access database. The code runs fine and even says that data entry is successful, but upon checking the database file no new row entry is made.

```
Public Class NewDelivery
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Public Shared stxtboxsupsel As TextBox
Public Shared supnum As String
Public Shared dgvitems As DataGridView
Private Sub NewDelivery_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
Private Function OpenDBConnection()
    If My.Settings.DatabaseLoc = "" Then
        Dim directory As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        Return "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & directory & "\IE156.mdb"
    Else
        Return "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.DatabaseLoc
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    My.Forms.ManageInventory.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub btnSelSupp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelSupp.Click
    My.Forms.SelectSupplier.Show()
    stxtboxsupsel = txtboxsupsel
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    con.ConnectionString = OpenDBConnection()
    con.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Delivery(ItemPurchDate,SupNum) VALUES (@ItemPurchDate,@SupNum)"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemPurchDate", DateTimePicker1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupNum", supnum)
    con.Close()
    Me.Close()
    MsgBox("New Delivery Recorded")
End Sub
```

The Delivery Table has 3 columns namely ItemPurchNum (Primary Key and Autonumber), ItemPurchDate(date/time) and SupNum(Number and has a many to one relationship with SupNum from my Supplier table).

I had no trouble adding new rows in my other forms following the similar code. Any thoughts on why it won't add a new row? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello - I don't see the cmd.Execute() - or equivalent...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. Noticed that I skipped a line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), and now it works!